# Is it possible to control position of page action in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to add an icon to the addressbar. It works fine, but there are other extensions which adds such an icon too. I can't see the logic behind the ordering of these icons.

At home my icon is at the very left position and at work it is somewhere in the middle. I can't change it by dragging (like the buttons beside the addressbar).

Do you know if it is possible? And if yes, how?
Or which factor is responsible for the ordering?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that the order of how the extension has been installed is responsible for the ordering of that icons.

The latest installed extension appears leftmost.